# Calculate datediff using postgresql and produce number of years

Tags: sql, postgresql, datetime

I have two input date values and would like to calculate the difference between these dates (no of years) and store it as age

I have tried using the below psql command. However it results in decimal form. How can I round this and is there any other elegant method to write this?

```
select icu.intime, p.dob, EXTRACT('epoch' from icu.intime - p.dob) / 60.0 / 
60.0 / 24.0 / 365.242 as age from patients p inner join 
icustays icu on p.subject_id = icu.subject_id
```

Though I get the age value, I would like to round it off.[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use age function

```
select age(intime,dob)
```

so in your case it would be

```
select icu.intime, p.dob, age(icu.intime,p.dob) as number_age from patients p inner join 
icustays icu on p.subject_id = icu.subject_id
```

use extract year if you need just yeara

```
EXTRACT(YEAR from (age(icu.intime,p.dob)))
```

Comment: Okay, I used Round function and it worked. Guess that was syntax issue. However, I would like to know whether I can get only the 'Year' component from your 'age' function like 65,66 IN NUMERIC format and not like 65 years.. I don't wish to month,days etc

Comment: just extract year from age

Comment: @SELVA Note that `age()` returns an **interval** and `extract(year from age(...))` only returns the complete years from that. So if the age is e.g. 11 month `extract(year from age(...))` would return `0`